# Problem with power on in dual boot ubuntu system?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, data-recovery, error-handling

When I turned on my laptop i get this window view and nothing is working; I don't have idea what to do.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/szwhF.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

While booting hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> or<kbd>ESC</kbd> to open GRUB. Select the 2nd option that says recovery mode. In the next menu select root and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
You should now see something like this:

```
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Remount the partition to get write privileges

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Then edit this /etc/gdm3/custom.conf using:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Then un-comment the line:

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

So now it says

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>y</kbd> to save and exit.
Then

```
reboot
```